# How do I run a Plack request handler in background?

Tags: multithreading, perl, plack

I have a simple Plack app (something like [Plack::App::GitHub::WebHook](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack%3a%3aApp%3a%3aGitHub%3a%3aWebHook)) that I run using `plackup`. I perform a lengthy operation in the request handler, which currently makes the app unresponsive to subsequent requests until the operation is finished. How can I perform the operation in background, without blocking other requests? And a follow-up question, how can I keep at most one job running in that background queue?

I’m used to [libdispatch](https://libdispatch.macosforge.org), so I’d love something like this:

```
my $queue = Hypothetical::Concurrency::Queue->new(max_jobs => 1);
$queue->dispatch(sub {
    # code
});
```

Comment: You'll want a multi-process plack server (starman is popular) for the first, and some form of lock for the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just realized there’s one very important distinction I forgot to make: I don’t have to wait for the job to finish to respond to the HTTP request. Which means I’m fine with [Forks::Super](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Forks%3a%3aSuper):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Forks::Super MAX_PROC => 1, ON_BUSY => 'queue';

my $app = sub {
    my $env = shift;
    fork sub {
        # lengthy operation
    };
    return [202, ['Content-Type'=>'text/plain', 'Content-Length'=>8], ["Accepted"]];
};
```

Now servicing the request finishes immediately, the long operation runs in background and there’s always at most one of them running. `Forks::Super` looks complex and takes ages to install, so I’d be happy if someone knows a more lightweight module offering a similar feature.

Comment: Maybe `202 Accepted` would be a better choice than `200 OK` in this case?